# How to debug call to WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webrequest, webmethod

I'm implementing an aspx website. I have a page with several webmethod.

by example :

```
public partial class MyWebService : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetProfileInformations(int userId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm calling this method from a C#/winform heavy client. 
All work fine in my dev environment (IIS 7.5). But in production (Also IIS 7.5 but maybe with something different in the configuration) my heavy client got an error 500 from the server when I call a webmethod with argument.

Below the code of my heavy client that perform the request to the webmethod :

```
    private JObject DoWebRequest(string webMethod, string parameters)
    {
        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceRootUrl"] + webMethod;
        HttpWebRequest theWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        theWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        theWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        theWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        theWebRequest.UserAgent = "Acet BadgeReader 1.0";
        theWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Pragma] = "no-cache";
        theWebRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
        theWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        theWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        theWebRequest.PreAuthenticate=true;

        using (var writer = theWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
            writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
        }


        string resultData = null;
        try
        {

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)theWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    resultData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    resultData = resultData.Trim();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

As parameter are build dinamically, I supposed that an error in the parameter string could explain this error 500. And That right, if I called the webmethod GetProfileInformations with a wrong parameter (by example by setting parameters string with "{\"user\":}" instead of "{\"userId\": 10}", I got an error 500 from the server, but impossible to catch this error in the aspx code, or to retrieve log in IIS... so what appends :( ? Is it possible to catch this kind of error in the aspx code ?

**EDIT :**

Thanks for yours comments. So I used Fiddler I catch some new information, below the answer of a bad request :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
jsonerror: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 10:00:46 GMT
Content-Length: 91

{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

But unfortunatly Error message is not very helpfull. Maybe error message could be more verbose if IIS is properly configured...

Comment: Maybe try something like Fiddler and inspect what is being sent in the request and responses?

Comment: Try catching it in Application_Error in Global.asax: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

Comment: Thanks you, I have updated the main question with what I found with Fiddler. And unfortunatly this error cannot be catch with the Application_Error in Global.asax.